# Allow user profile update without password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I need advice how to model allow update of model without validation if current user is admin. I've made a simple User model:

```
create_table "user", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "username",
    t.string   "password",
    t.string   "description",
    t.string   "title",
    t.boolean  "disabled"
end
```

All users can update their profile by providing a password again. Admin has an option to disable user like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Disable', user_path(user, :user => {:disabled => true}), :method => :put %>
```

The problem is that inside my model I have the following validation:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 10 }
```

After admin triggers action to disable user, error shows that password is too short and that it needs to be minimum 10 characters long. How can I disable that validation for admin?

Answer (score 0):

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 10 }, :unless => :admin?

def admin?
  self.role == "Admin"
end
```

P.S: I don't know how what you have to check to know if the user is admin. I am assuming that you have a role column

Comment: Thank you. I need something similar. The only thing is admin can edit all users so self.role doesn't work because that is for the user which is edited. I have a helper where I can check is user an admin but it now I see I can't access that helper's method inside my model.